# What is the best practice for standing up Rest services that includes EJBs (Stateless, Singelton) for JBOSS EAP 7.2.2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I am having a hard time injecting some EJB's into my REST application.
The server won't start up.
I get ths exception:

```
20:22:23,350 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."exampleEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."exampleEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "example.war" of deployment "exampleEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"
```

Here is a more robust Stack Trace (That is still unfortunately vague):

```
12:59:25,431 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example-app.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."example-appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"."example-app.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "example-app.war" of deployment "example-appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Failed to link javax/faces/webapp/FacetTag (Module "deployment.example-appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.example-app.war:main" from Service Module Loader): Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/webapp/FacetTag
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:605)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:21)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:14)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:84)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
        ... 5 more

12:59:25,439 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "example-appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"example-appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"example-app.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"example-appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"example-app.war\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"example-app.war\" of deployment \"example-appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\"
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Failed to link javax/faces/webapp/FacetTag (Module \"deployment.example-appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear.example-app.war:main\" from Service Module Loader): Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/webapp/FacetTag"},
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"example-appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"example-appEAR-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.ear\".beanmanager]"]
```

I have 2 EJB Jars that do supposedly communicate with each other
I do have a ton of session beans (@Singleton, @Stateless) in each of the underlying EJB jars that I am trying to reference in my WAR.  To make matters worse, my WAR is also an EJB (@Stateless).

I suspect I need to simplify this whole application to get it to work.  But is there a best practice for installing an Ear that includes a WAR that is an EJB, that also includes 2 EJB's that contain multiple Session Beans (@Singleton, @Stateless)?

Here is an example of my code (not my actual code):

```
@Stateless
public class ExampleResource{
 @Context
 UriInfo uriInfo;

 @Context
 SecurityContext securityContext; 

 @Inject
 IExampleResourceEJB exampleResourceEJB;

      public Resonse getExampleResource(){
             String result = exampleResourceEJB.getResourceValue();
             return Response.ok(result).build();
      }
 }
}

@Default
@Stateless
public class ExampleResourceEJB implements IExampleResourceEJB{
      @Inject 
      IExampleResourceEJB erejb;
      public String getResourceValue(){
            return "getThatStrBruh"
      }
}

@Default
@Stateless
public class ExampleResourceEJB1 implements IExampleResourceEJB{
      public String getResourceValue(){
            return "getThatStrBruh"
      }
}
```

That is an example of how my project is set up.  It is not perfect and probably won't compile on an IDE but that is what i have set up.
Those EJB classes are packaged in two different jars.  Those Jars are Packaged in the EAR (not the war).  Is that a good patter?

Comment: You need to provide more information about your deployment, and the error. You posted only one line of the error; usually, error logs have stack traces, and the final cause of the problem is hidden somewhere in the trace. Adittionally, you need to provide more details about how you injected the dependency in your REST application. Please post code of the REST componente, the EJB, and the web.xml in the REST application. There's a lot that can conspire to fail a deployment...

Comment: No offense to you SoftwareSavant and I've seen you around these parts frequently but I think its funny that Martin's telling you to provide more info when you've got more reputation than him - again, just funny, dont take it the wrong way please.

Comment: And also, I use JBoss daily and for about ten years and I seriously "feel you" - they have some of the worst and most obscure errors when deployments fail!  Very frustrating to figure things out when they could just say, you know, you annotated this wrong or have it in web.xml but the annotations screwing things up :-/

Comment: I usually try and post as little code as possible as per policies of my employer.  Hope you understand.  That being said I can add more details, I will see if I can't expand the stack trace.  But really, I have all that information in another Stack Overflow question.  I guess the crux of this question is what is the best practice for Standing up a REST api that utilizes EJB's On JBOSS EAP 7.2 (This app starts up on WAS 85).  Should I be packaging the EJB's at the EAR level? the JAR level?  Should I have a more verbose ejb-jar.xml, I am using CDI so do I need a more robust beans.xml

Comment: Oh, completely understood there!  More details from the stack trace will probably help, as theres usually a little more clues as to whats wrong other than the dreaded line you provided, I know its a pain to sanitize it!  Ditto some of what might be in the web.xml thats EJB related or the annotations for any implementations and or interfaces.  And I see you updated the question while I was typing ;-)

Comment: So it does work on WAS, and I take it WAS is Wildfly application server? In my experience which is always JBoss EAP7 and EAR related, we always have An EJB and WAR in the EAR, though at times it could be just one or the other.  In the WAR, if we reference an EJB, its and EJB in the EJB Jar packaging.  Jboss EAP 7, you dont really need to use the ejb-jar.xml entries file anymore for anything simple as long as you have annotations, and I use CDI for resources (like strings), or timers, or JMSContext but they're all just annotations except for the string resources which come from the ejb-jar.xml.

Comment: @JGlass, "WAS" is usually a reference to WebSphere (Application Server).

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the clarification - and I think I knew that in the deep recesses of my mind but was on a JBoss tangent ;-)  Did you get it figured out? Ooh, that stacktrace helps, I've see this before `ClassFormatError: Failed to link javax/faces/webapp/FacetTag`, ah carp - where I had seen it was our own discussion on your other post!  Did my last comment help at all, I can research further

Comment: I think I have your answer - give me a minute

Comment: Are you bundling a JavaServer Faces library in your application or using whats provided by the app server runtime?  Also are you using Maven?